# install4j: How to Obtain Old JRE -OR- Convert Installer to .tar.gz?

Tags: bundle, java, install4j

I accepted a project that consists of a Java-project that is shipped with an installer built by install4j (we have a license for 4.2.8). I'm required to ship a JRE with it. The problem is that the guy who worked on it before me left and I don't have access to his installation of install4j that would have included the JREs that are currently shipped with the final installer of our project (Java 1.6.0_29).

Within install4j I can select a JRE, but 1.6.0_29 is not listed there any more. My obvious option was to simply use the latest 1.6-version, but that was declined. Therefore, now I don't have a JRE. I can't even build a bundle with install4j since none of my colleagues has that version. Besides that, I'd need it for all our target platforms (Windows, Linux and MacOS).

I think the only options I have now is to

- find a hidden gem on the internet that holds old JREs in .tar.gz-format (i.e., if you know such a site please let me know)
- download the various installers from Oracle's site and somehow convert them into .tar.gz (however, I have no idea how to convert, e.g. an exe, into a .tar.gz)

I tried to figure out where install4j downloads the bundles. I played around with the URLs, but it seems as if only those listed in install4j are available.

Do I have another option? Does anyone have solutions for the two options I listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ["createbundle" command line tool](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/jreBundle.html) to create a JRE bundle from any installed JRE.

This is available since install4j 5.0. You can install the current version with an evaluation key and the created bundle .tar.gz file will work for 4.x as well.

Bundling a JRE for Mac OS X is not supported in install4j 4.x. This functionality was added in install4j 5.1 for OpenJDK on Mac OS X.

Comment: I can build JRE bundles with 4.2.8 already. However, installing all the versions on all the platforms would require some work (maybe in connection with VirtualBox or similar software). Due to that I'm looking for a simpler way for this. -- Thanks for the info about MacOS. I checked the configuration file and install4j doesn't provide a property `includedJRE` for a MacOS-installer.

Comment: There is no way other that to install install4j on the target platform. createbundle is helpful if you do not have a GUI available like on a remote Linux machine.

Comment: Oh, I thought I could use my Windows installation of install4j and remotely access the JRE-installation on the target machine/platform. Well, maybe that wouldn't work because of different newlines? Hmm.